# select multiple with JsonWireProtocol

Tags: javascript, php, selenium

I use own library for functional testing in PHP, it's based on [JsonWireProtocol](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol).

I have an select element selected by id and I need to select 2 options from this element. I know how to select singe element - I just find desired option and [click](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/%3asessionId/element/%3aid/click) on it. But it's impossible with 2 options as second click deselects first one.

How can I achieve this?

As workaround I send a JavaScript line but I'm not happy with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the JsonWireProtocol draft version I understand that Selenium interprets modifier-keys such as ctrl and shift as sticky. http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/keys and code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/keys

So I haven't tested this myself, but it seems to me that you can send a ctrl-keypress, follow by two clicks on the options you want to select, and then another ctrl-keypress to "depress" the ctrl-key.